# how to put different cell values if I have more than one sections?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have two sections in my UITableView, in one view I want to show data from one NSMutableArray say AArray and in other sections I want to show the data from other NSMutableArray say BArray

how can i achieve such concept?

Comment: You should be more specific in your question about the programming language and library you're using. Also add some tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look at the index path.

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
    // Use array A
else
    // Use array B
```